# WPF Popup: Not showing image inside it, rounded corners issue and popup not being horizontally centered

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, popup

Below my WPF Popup control attached to a stackpanel "pnlTopMenu":

```
<Popup Name="popMessage" 
       StaysOpen="True" IsOpen="{Binding IsPopupOpen}" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
       PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=pnlTopMenu}" Placement="Bottom"
       PopupAnimation="Scroll" AllowsTransparency="True">
    <Border CornerRadius="0,0,10,10" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            BorderBrush="DarkBlue" BorderThickness="1"  
            Background="AntiqueWhite">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Image Source="./Resources/Info_48.png" Height="20"/>
            <TextBlock Width="90" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                   Background="Transparent" FontSize="12">This is a Popup</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

Three problems here:

1. Image is correctly shown in visual studio designer but not at run
   time.
2. Also I had to make background transparent for textbox because if
   not, it was overlapping with rounded corners for popup and then
   corners were not being shown as rounded.
3. Popup is not being horizontally centered at the bottom of the stackpanel.

   Why?

**UPDATE**:

First problem was due to image build action. It was added to my resources folder within my visual studio project, but the build action was not set to resource. So changing it to resource, the image is shown.

The other two problems I am already trying to solve it.